# Past Participial Relatives are the sourse of Participial Adjectives, why?

Tags: syntax, adjectives, participles

I came across this statement in a work (Ph.D. Dissertation, p.158) by Asier Alcázar Estela in which he assumes that the Past Participial Relatives are the source of the Participial Adjectives. And he provides the following example:

*the recently arrived train < the train [recently arrived]*

I couldn't see how this example can stand as an argument for his assumption. 
If anyone has an idea, please help.

Comment: Is this about English, or about some perceived "universal"?

Comment: about English, as he claims.

Comment: There's no participial adjective here, nor a relative clause. What makes you think there are?

Comment: Quoting from page 158, "Third, PPRs are the source of participial adjectives (e.g., the recently arrived train < the train [recently arrived]). The next three sections address each point in generative grammar."

Comment: http://digitallibrary.usc.edu/cdm/ref/collection/p15799coll127/id/555904   this is the link of his dissertation.

Comment: "recently arrived" is the result of whiz-deletion. on a relative  clause.